# Weyl transformation of the metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, cosmological-inflation

In this reference https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09975

> Ketov, et al. “Extending Starobinsky Inflationary Model in Gravity and Supergravity.” *[1809.09975] Extending Starobinsky Inflationary Model in Gravity and Supergravity*, 24 Sept. 2018, arxiv.org/abs/1809.09975.

Has some one an idea how to make the Weyl transformation of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, Equation (3) , and how to get the potential (4) from the action (3) by this transformation as explained after (3) ?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: If the OP is not aware of Weyl Transformation, the Wiki page on the same is really handy and useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_transformation

Answer (score 1):

Weyl transformation is transformation of metric, of the form
$$
g^{mn}\rightarrow\Omega g^{mn},~~~g_{mn}\rightarrow\Omega^{-1}g_{mn},
$$
where $\Omega$ is some function of the coordinates. This leads to the transformation
$$
\sqrt{-g}\rightarrow\Omega^{-2}\sqrt{-g},
$$
where $g={\rm det}g_{mn}$.

In this paper the Weyl transformation parameter is $\Omega=F'(\chi)$ (it is chosen to obtain Einstein frame action). 
The scalar potential in eqn. (3) is
$$
\frac{1}{2}(F'(\chi)\chi-F(\chi)).
$$
Then, Weyl rescaling of $\sqrt{-g}$ multiplies it by $1/F'^2$. Hope this helps.